# Summing the number of times a value appears in either of 2 columns

Tags: r, data.table

I have a large data set - around 32mil rows. I have information on the telephone number, the origin of the call, and the destination.

For each telephone number, I want to count the number of times it appeared either as Origin or as Destination.

An example data table is as follows:

```
library(data.table)
dt <- data.table(Tel=seq(1,5,1), Origin=seq(1,5,1), Destination=seq(3,7,1))

    Tel Origin Destination 
1:   1      1           3 
2:   2      2           4
3:   3      3           5 
4:   4      4           6 
5:   5      5           7
```

I have working code, but it takes too long for my data since it involves a for loop. How can I optimize it?

Here it is:

```
for (i in unique(dt$Tel)){
    index <- (dt$Origin == i | dt$Destination == i)
    dt[dt$Tel ==i, "N"] <- sum(index)
}
```

Result:

```
    Tel Origin Destination N
1:   1      1           3  1
2:   2      2           4  1
3:   3      3           5  2
4:   4      4           6  2
5:   5      5           7  2
```

Where N tells that Tel=1 appears 1, Tel=2 appears 1, Tel=3,4 and 5 each appear 2 times.

Comment: Please note that it is not the `for` loop that is the issue *per se*, but how you are performing the operation.

Comment: Maybe you should consider using graph theory here, with the igraph package (telephone numbers as nodes, calls as directed edges).

Answer (score 1):

We can do a `melt` and `match`

```
dt[, N := melt(dt, id.var = "Tel")[, tabulate(match(value, Tel))]]
```

---

Or another option is to loop through the columns 2 and 3, use `%in%` to check whether the values in 'Tel' are present, then with `Reduce` and `+` get the sum of logical elements for each 'Tel', assign (`:=`) the values to 'N'

```
dt[, N := Reduce(`+`, lapply(.SD, function(x) Tel %in% x)), .SDcols = 2:3]
dt
#   Tel Origin Destination N
#1:   1      1           3 1
#2:   2      2           4 1
#3:   3      3           5 2
#4:   4      4           6 2
#5:   5      5           7 2
```

Comment: but you code produced the following results, which is not correct. I got for the first two telephone numbers N=3 and N=4, not 1, as it should be. But I will check once again.

Comment: @RalucaGui  My code is giving the expected output you showed in the post

Comment: Correct, my mistake! The code runs smoothly. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

A second method constructs a temporary data.table which is then joins to the original. This is longer and likely less efficient than @akrun's, but can be useful to see.

```
# get temporary data.table as the sum of origin and destination frequencies
temp <- setnames(data.table(table(unlist(dt[, .(Origin, Destination)], use.names=FALSE))),
                 c("Tel", "N"))
# turn the variables into integers (Tel is the name of the table above, and thus character)
temp <- temp[, lapply(temp, as.integer)]
```

Now, join the original table on

```
dt <- temp[dt, on="Tel"]
dt
   Tel N Origin Destination
1:   1 1      1           3
2:   2 1      2           4
3:   3 2      3           5
4:   4 2      4           6
5:   5 2      5           7
```

You can get the desired column order using `setcolorder`

```
setcolorder(dt, c("Tel", "Origin", "Destination", "N"))
```